# How to mock standard package function for unit test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have three functions:

```
func IsSymlinks(path string) {
   ...
   ...
}

func (c *MyClass) myFunc1(path string) {
  ...more code
  ...more code
  if IsSymlinks(path) {
    realPath := filepath.EvalSymlinks(path)
  }
  ...more code
  ...more code
}

func myFunc2(path string) {
      ...more code
      ...more code
      if IsSymlinks(path) {
        realPath := filepath.EvalSymlinks(path)
      }
      ...more code
      ...more code
    }
```

How do I test myFunc1 and myFunc2 by mocking filepath.EvalSymlinks and IsSymlinks? I searched some posts and saw several solutions.

1. Create a EvalSymlinks variable of function type, initialized with filepath.EvalSymlinks, and then in the test package, change it to my implementation. However, I prefer not to use this approach.
2. Pass in filepath.EvalSymlinks and IsSymlinks into myFunc as parameter. I prefer not to use this way either.
3. A lot of people talk about mocking use interface. Could you please help? Or another approach that could test myFunc? Thank you!
4. Another option I am thinking is if it is a good practice to create a symlink in os to a path before I do the function test, and then delete the symlink right after testing?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using an interface. For example let's say you have an interface called Linker:

```
type Linker interface {
    IsSymlinks(path String)
}
```

Now you can embed a Linker object into the function that calls the `IsSymlinks` method.

```
type MyClass struct {
    Linker
}

func (p *MyClass) myFunc(path String) {
    _ = p.Linker.IsSymlinks(path)
}
```

Now in your test you can create a mock Linker.

```
type mockLinker struct{}
//implement the IsSymlinks on the mockLinker as you wish

p := &MyClass{
    Linker: mockLinker,
}

p.myFunc(path)
```

when `p.myFunc` reaches the `IsSymlinks` method it calls your mocked `IsSymlinks` method.

For `filepath.EvalSymlinks(path)` you can wrap that method in another method that is yours and add the new method to the same interface and mock that method instead of mocking the `EvalSymlinks`.

Creating interfaces just for the purpose of testing may not always be the best idea as in some cases may result in having large interfaces which are not idiomatic in Go as it makes the code less readable.

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution! I totally agree with your last paragraph. I saw a similar idea in another post and I hesitate to use it since it is kind of difficult to persuade myself to add another field in MyClass just for testing two small functions. I would like to see if there is any other solution. If not, I will go with this interface approach. Thank you again!

Comment: Since I update my question, the above answer may not easily apply to my case.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to test your new `IsSymlinks` function since it's not a method anymore. Only way I can think of is if core functionality inside `IsSymlinks` is a method on a global object that can be mocked.

Interfaces should generally be used in cases where an object may change but the behaviour is the same. If this is the case then an interface is the right approach.

Your option #4 can be used as long as the tests don't become flaky in the sense that for example the symlink actually is not yet created before the test runs or properly deleted after.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to design in a different way your MyClass struct and the related functions. I mean to get indipendent your MyClass object from packages like filepath. First, create a new interface that have two functions:

```
type MyEvalLink interface {
    IsSymlinks(path string) bool
    EvalSymlinks(path string) (string, error)
}
```

Then you can implement both the two functions in a struct that use the filepath package or a fake code:

```
type EvalLinkUse struct{}

func (p *EvalLinkUse) IsSymlinks(path string) bool {
  // put here your real code or fake
}

func (p *EvalLinkUse) EvalSymlinks(path string) (string, error) {
  // put here your real code or fake
}
```

So, your code will change as follow:

```
type MyClass struct {
    ...your code
    MyEvalLink MyEvalLink
} 



func (c *MyClass) myFunc1(path string) {
  ...more code
  ...more code
  if c.MyEvalLink.IsSymlinks(path) {
    realPath := c.MyEvalLink.EvalSymlinks(path)
  }
  ...more code
  ...more code
}
```

Could that fit your case?

Comment: Thanks! I understand it works for myFun1, but I am not sure how I can use it to test myFunc2 which is not part of any class.

Comment: Thank you! In the playground, my understanding is in order to test myFunc3 with EvalLinkUse from MyClass, in the test, I need to create another function(myFunc2) to replace the EvalLinkUse with MockEvalLinkUse. If my understanding is correct, I prefer not to duplicate code(myFunc2). Besides, MyClass is a large struct, I am not sure if it is a good practice to create it only to use two of its functions(Sorry I am new to Go).

Comment: I agree with you, the DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) is a good rule of thumb. Go support composition instead of inheritance that I used for a long time, maybe someone else could suggest a better solution.